# Find Double/Float value is Odd or Even in C#

Tags: c#, double

How to find if `double` value is *even* or *odd* without converting them to `int` in C#? E.g.

```
123.0d     - odd
456.0d     - even
3.1415926d - floating point (neither odd nor even)
```

Comment: How would you find out if an `int` is even or odd?

Comment: I'm confused. Is 2.5 odd or even?

Comment: if(int%2 == 0) even else odd

Comment: @RaviReddy Congrats, you have  your answer.

Comment: What's bad in converting the double to int? Is it homework? What's your effort?

Comment: If i convert to int, then there is no point of  using double.

Comment: @RaviReddy - Exactly. Why are you using `double` in the first place if you need to check for odd/even? And you haven't answered the question if `2.5` is odd or even, yet.

Comment: so what i have to do to check a value is even or odd

Comment: I have some values with some difference between them like 100.05,100.10,100.15,100.20,100.25,100.30...... Now i need to find the mean which should lie in that numbers only. sometimes the mean cannot exists in those values so i need value which is near to mean

Comment: @RaviReddy - Okay, great! Those are the values you have. Now for each of those values, what would you expect a method should return in terms of odd or even?

Comment: Purely guessing: `100.05`, `100.15` and `100.25` are probably odd-*ish* while `100.10`, `100.20` and `100.30` are even-*ish*, right? Do all the values you work with have exactly two decimal places?

Comment: @RaviReddy - wait... you want to find the value in a collection closest to the mean? Where does odd/even come into place o_O? Nevermind. How about: `var values = new[] { 100.10, 100.15, 100.20, 100.25, 100.30 }; var exactMean = values.Select(x => x / values.Length).Sum(); var closestToMean = values.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x - exactMean)).First();`

Answer (score 6):

Try modulo `%` operator:

```
 double x = 123;

 string result = x % 2 == 0 
    ? "even" : x % 2 == 1 || x % 2 == -1
    ? "odd"
    : "floating point"; // e.g. 123.456789
```

**Edit:** When does it work? Floating point value (`single`, `double`) when it doesn't contain *exponential part* represents the (integer) value *exactly*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

So we have that the solution will work whenever `x` in these ranges

```
[-2**24..2**24] == [-16777216..16777216]                 (float)
[-2**52..2**52] == [-4503599627370496..4503599627370496] (double)
```

Please, notice, that since .Net assumes that `negative % positive == nonpostive`, e.g. `-3 % 2 == -1` we *have to check* `x % 2 == -1` as well as `x % 2 == 1`

Comment: @CodeCaster: when `double` represents small *integer value* there's no round up errors: `double` has just an integer mantissa https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: negative 1 ???   oh, I get it... nice

Comment: @Joe: yes, according to .Net `-3 % 2 == -1`

Comment: That's a nice edit (I don't need credit), have an upvote.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thank you for your *good question* (request for edit) in the comments which helped me improve my *premature* answer.

Answer (score 0):

well i think you answered your question by your own but here is a short code i wrote:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double number=10.0;

        if(number%2==0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your number is even!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your number is odd!");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

this way you see really good if it works or not

Comment: what if `number == 3.1415926`? Your routine returns `"Your number is odd!"` which sounds a bit *odd*...

Answer (score -2):

```
public bool isEven(double value)
{
   decimal decVal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(value);
    if (decVal % 2.0 == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** if you convert to a decimal first it should work.

Comment: What if I want to test for `odd`?

Comment: `return value % 2 == 0`

Comment: I already tried this, but no use

Comment: if isEven() returns false then your value is odd.

Comment: So `3.2` is odd?

Answer (score -2):

```
public static bool IsEven(double x)
{
      return x % 2 == 0;
}
```

Please note that it takes more code to make a helper method that does this than it does to actually do it, so if you ever put this in a production environment expect your QA team to send you nasty e-mails.

Comment: Your QA team looks at the code and code reviews it?  That seems rather odd.  I'd only expect the code to be reviewed by other programmers.  That said, were I reviewing code that had this method, I *certainly* wouldn't suggest removing it.  Small methods aren't problematic at all.

Comment: It's called *abstraction* - one of the 4 pillars of OOP. `foo = IsEven(x)` is more expressive than `foo = x % 2 == 0;`, *especially* if you have that logic inlined in 200 places.